# Hibernate 5: how to join a HashMap in the HQL?

Tags: hibernate, join, hql, hibernate-mapping

Suppose, I have an entity Country extends Entity. Every entity should have some kind of metadata (translation, description, createdate etc...).

```
public abstract class Entity<T> implements Serializable {
    protected Map<Language,EntityMetaData> metaData;
    // constructors, setters, getters etc.
}

public class Country extends Entity<Long> implements Serializable {
    // some fields
    // constructors, setters, getters etc.
}

public class EntityMetaData extends Entity<Long> implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Language language;
    // constructors, setters, getters etc.
}
```

Here is my mapping for Country:

```
<class name="Country" table="COUNTRIES" schema="EDRIVE" dynamic-update="false" dynamic-insert="true" batch-size="30">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains countries
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="isoCode2" column="isocode2" type="string" length="2"/>
    <property name="isoCode3" column="isocode3" type="string" length="3"/>
    <property name="telephoneCode" column="telephonecode" type="int"/>
    <property name="timezone" column="timezone" type="boolean"/>
    <!--+
        | CountriesMetaData
        +-->
    <map name="metaData" fetch="join" cascade="all" batch-size="10" table="CountriesMetaData">
        <key column="entityId"/>
        <map-key-many-to-many column="languageId" class="Language"/>
        <one-to-many entity-name="countriesMetaData"/>
    </map>
</class>
```

and for EntityMetaData:

```
<class name="EntityMetaData" entity-name="countriesMetaData" table="COUNTRIESMETADATA" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="id" access="field">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string" length="256" />
    <property name="description" column="description" type="string" length="512"/>
    <many-to-one name="language" class="Language" column="languageid" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

So, what I need: I would like to have a countries list with all theirs metadatas. I use following HQL:

```
List<Country> countryList = (List<Country>)databaseUtilities.getSession()
            .createQuery("FROM Country c JOIN FETCH c.metaData m")
            .list();
```

Hibernate selects everything as well (and I even see all collections initialized in debug), but Country.metaData remains PersistentMap (instead of HashMap I want), and I receive null when I try to:

```
EntityMetaData entityMetaData = metaData.get(locale.getDisplayName());
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

P.S. Hibernate 5.0.3.Final

Answer (score 0):

PersistentMap is a wrapper for Map, you can easily retrieve it. Did you try this?

`Map metaData = country.getMetaData();`

Comment: Yes, I did. It returns PersistentMap.

Comment: Inside the transaction, right after executing the query? PersistentMap wraps together the session and the map. You need the session object to extract the map from the wrap.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I am rewriting my DAOImpl class in order to perform conversion inside of one transaction. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703851/how-to-fetch-a-map-in-hibernate for details.